# How can I create a pandas DataFrame with keys from a dictionary as my index? [Python, pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this dictionary:

d = {'Name1': (33, 'String1'), 'Name2': (59, 'String2')}

And all I want to do is print a DataFrame with pandas, where the index are my keys and I'll have two columns where I'll put the values of the respective keys in it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you referring to `Name1` being the column with two values `33` and `String1`?  Did you try to do a simple `df = pd.DataFrame(d).T` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the keys of the dictionary to be the index then you can do this:

```
d = {'Name1': (33, 'String1'), 'Name2': (59, 'String2')}
df=pd.DataFrame(d.values(),index=d.keys())
print(df)
```

output:

```
        0        1
Name1  33  String1
Name2  59  String2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback! That's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: you can use `df = df.rename(columns={0:'column1',1:'column2'})` to get those renamed

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['column A', 'column B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this. Just create the dataframe using `d` and then transpose the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Name1': (33, 'String1'), 'Name2': (59, 'String2')}
df=pd.DataFrame(d).T
df = df.rename(columns={0:'column1',1:'column2'})
print (df)
```

If you want a single line, then it is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(d).T.rename(columns={0:'column1',1:'column2'})
```

The output will be as follows:

```
      column1  column2
Name1      33  String1
Name2      59  String2
```